# What is the correct syntax in Angular?

Tags: angular

When I enter this code

```
{{ (n.variation<0?-n.variation:n.variation) | number:'1.2-2' | testformatnum }}&nbsp;%
<span *ngIf="n.variation >= 0"
```

On Visual Studio Code, the value `'1.2-2'` becomes red , I have the same problem with `<span`.

[image]

Do you think this is a problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should close your declaration before the  tag, just like this:

```
{{ (n.variation<0?-n.variation:n.variation) | number:'1.2-2' | testformatnum }}&nbsp;%}}
<span *ngIf="n.variation >= 0">...</span>
```

Maybe this fixes your problem!